# Get creative id in VAST 2.0/3.0

Tags: vast

How to get Creative Id in which an error? I use the macros [ERRORCODE] for error ad handling that catсh in  tag. Perhaps there is a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no IAB macro for the ad id, but it should be known to your ad server which is serving the creative xml, just use the ad server macro to insert the id into the error tracker.